# How do I identify what code is generating " '' is not a valid floating point value" error dialogue box

Tags: delphi, error-handling, debugging

I am using Delphi 2010 and have a program which keeps generating an error dialog box stating

'' is not a valid floating point value

How do I get delphi to show me the line that generated that error?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to solve this is to run under the debugger and have it configured to **Notify on language exceptions**, Tools | Options:

[image]

Ignore the big list of exceptions to ignore that come from my own codebase. Just make sure the checkbox I have highlighted is marked.

Then when you run your program, it will stop at the line that causes the exception.

Comment: Thanks for this quick response David.  I have Delphi 2010 and the Notify on Language Exceptions is already ticked .. any other ideas.

Comment: @robert Do you have debugging enabled in the compiler options? Try with debug DCUs too. Which exceptions are ignored, i.e. on you machine what's in the "Exceptions to ignore" list box?

Comment: @robert: Uncheck EConvertError in the list above.

Comment: @Ulrich Thanks, that's the one!

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for StrToFloat function. This function raises an exception if the parameter is an empty string. You can replace the function call with:

if Trim(StrV) = '' then StrV := '0.0';
f := StrToFloat(StrV);

Comment: Lifesaver - what a star; I was assuming that the problem was coming from how I was using Font.Color and Brush.Color in a dbgrids OnDrawColumnCell method, but it was actually arising within the code for an onform teechart linked to a database.  Many thanks.

Comment: Or just use `StrToFloatDef(StrV, 0.0)` instead. That saves the function call to Trim and separate string assignment. `StrToFloatDef` is in SysUtils. You might also want to know about `StrToIntDef` in that unit also.