# '' Is Not a Valid Identifier (Delphi XE5)

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe5

I'm new to Delphi XE5 (part of Embarcadero's RAD Studio), and using the StrToFloat function in a VCL Forms project designed to build a simple calculator.

The code to display the text to the user works well, but I'm having trouble extracting it in a way that will allow the calculator to actually perform calculations. The means I've settled on is displaying the code to the user in a Tedit, and storing the code to be executed in a Tmemo. Pressing the buttons on the calculator stores the numbers to both, and pressing an operator (the symbols for add, subtract, exponent, multiply, and divide) starts a new line in the memo. This way, each number is on its own line, and each operator is on its own line.

I then want to extract the numbers with respect to the operators,  by iterating through the lines of the memo. For `3 ^ 4`, you would see...

```
3
^
4
```

...in the TMemo.

I want to find the ^ sign at line index 1 (lines start at index 0, right?), and store `3` in a `base` variable by the logic that, ***if `^` is `lines[1]`, then `3` is `lines[1-1]`, or `lines[0]`***, and store `4` in an `exponent` variable. Both variables would be of type extended. This is the code I've created to do this...

```
 procedure TForm1.btnEqualsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  base: extended;
  exponent: extended;
  result: extended;
begin
  {This For loop looks for the exponentiation operator (^) in memCurrentEntry. If
   it's found, it then solves the equation.}
   for i := Low(memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text.Length) to High(memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text.Length) do
    if AnsiContainsStr(memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text, '^') then
    begin
        base := StrToFloat(memCurrentEntry.Lines[ansipos('^', memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text)-1]);
       exponent := StrToFloat(memCurrentEntry.Lines[ansiPos('^', memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text)+2]);
       result := power(base, exponent);
    end;
```

When I run the calculator, the numbers appear correctly, but when I hit the equals button to run the code above, I get the message **Project Calculator_u.exe raised exception class EConvertError with Message ''' is not a valid floating point value'.**

I know the StrToFloat function is trying to convert a null character or something ([How do I identify what code is generating " '' is not a valid floating point value" error dialogue box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089958/how-do-i-identify-what-code-is-generating-is-not-a-valid-floating-point-val)), but what should I do to correct this?

Below is the code for each button -- the digit (0, 1, 2, 3, etc.) changes, but the rest is the same for each one...

```
procedure TForm1.btn0Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Adds the digit  0 to the end of the current number in memCurrentEntry
  memCurrentEntry.SelStart := Length(memCurrentEntry.Text);
  memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text := Copy(memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text,1,
    memCurrentEntry.SelStart)+'0'+ Copy(memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text,
    memCurrentEntry.SelStart+1,Length(memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text)
    - memCurrentEntry.SelStart);

  //Adds the digit  0 to the end of the current number in edtCurrentEntry
  edtcurrententry.Text := edtcurrententry.Text + '0';
end;
```

I can post the full unit file upon request.

Comment: Could you please correct the question title. The Q has nothing at all to do with *'' Is Not a Valid Identifier*

Comment: First of all, Welcome to the Delphi Community!  Lots of information here which doesn't help identify the question.  One of the problems with this code is that it assumes that a ^ will always have a preceding number, so David's answer of using TryStrToFloat will address that specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`TryStrToFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToFloat). This returns a boolean indicating whether or not the conversion succeeded.

```
var
  str: string;
  val: Double;
....
if TryStrToFloat(str, val) then
  // val contains the floating point value represented by str
else
  // str does not contain a floating point value, do something else with it
```

Of course, you could use `StrToFloat`, and catch the exception. But since you expect to encounter the exception, it will result in much cleaner code if you use `TryStrToFloat`.

Comment: Okay. What's the advantage of that? Will TryStrToFloat still execute upon encountering the exception? How do I handle an exception in Pascal/Delphi?  (I've only been doing this for a few weeks).

Comment: Please don't ask us to teach you a language here. Please stick to specific questions. If you want to know what `TryStrToFloat` does, follow the link to the docs in the answer. I hope you did that already. Did you?

Comment: Didn't realize it was a link. I'm not asking you to teach me the language, I'm just trying to understand your answer.

Comment: "How do I handle an exception in Pascal/Delphi?" is a large question. It's not fair to ask it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

the usage of lines on the memo is wrong:

```
base := StrToFloat(memCurrentEntry.Lines[ansipos('^', memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text)-1]);
```

the lines.text returns the ENTIRE text, which is not what you want.  Instead use some LOCAL variables to hold your lookup values...that way you can set a breakpoint and see whats wrong and use the following method to locate the "^"

```
result := 0;
carrotLine := memCurrentEntry.Lines.IndexOf('^');
if carrotline > 0 then // must be 1 or greater, so a number can be at the 0 position
  begin
    base := TryStrToFloat(MemCurrentEntry.Lines[carrotLine-1],0);
    exponent := 0;
    // only try to read the next value if there is one.  
    if memCurrentEntry.Lines.Count >= carrotLine then
      exponent := TryStrToFloat(MemCurrentEntry.Lines[carrotline+1],0);
    result := power(base,exponent);
  end;
```

Note that this code ONLY handles a single ^ in the memo (your code had the same issue), to go beyond this is to use a loop and possibly a state engine or some other parsing logic to handle computations.

Comment: Any recommendations? I'd like to perform more than one calculation at a time, sort of like the built-in Microsoft Calculator, or most  scientific calculators. Once I get this working for the caret, I'll apply it to the other operands/operators/whatever. I understand the gist of your suggestion, but not the specifics of implementing it.

Comment: easiest way would be to use a stack. The concept of a stack where you push and pop works very well.  Think of it like enter number, press operator pushes number on stack and saves operator.  If operator is "=" then look at the operator and pop off the variables, pushing back the result.  so 2 + 2 = would pop both 2 entries off (the stack is now empty) perform the addition and push 4 on the stack.  entering then * 2 would pop off the 2 and the 4 from the stack multiply them and place 8 on the stack... clear of course would clear the stack.

Comment: OT: @skamradt, you can ask moderators to merge your profile with the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StrToFloat` is not wrong. If the conversion is failed, user should see an error message. If you want to suppress the error quietly, then you should add a try/except to protect your code.

```
try
  Value := StrToFloat(A_String);
except
  on EConvertError do
    Value := 0; // Fallback to a default value or execute other code logic
end;
```

According to your given code example, if the base and the exponent are entered in your given format (first line is the base, second line is a "^" and the third line is the exponent). I'd suggest you write your code as follows:

```
var
  Numbers: TArray<string>;
  // Other variables go here
begin
  // ...
  Numbers := memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text.Split('^'); 
  if Length(Numbers) = 2 then
  try
    Base := StrToFloat(Numbers[0]);
    Exponent := StrToFloat(Numbers[1]);
    Result := Power(Base, Exponent);
  except
    on EConvertError do
    begin
      ShowMessage(Format('Unable to calculate the formula %s', [memCurrentEntry.Lines.Text]));
      Result := 0; // Fallback to a default value, such as 0
    end;
  end;
  // ...
end;
```